# How to read multiple data sets with specific prefix pattern into global environment?

Tags: r, list, pattern-matching

I want to read a bunch of data sets (e. g. *.dta) with specific prefix and increasing number pattern into the global environment, and combine them in a list. (In this special case they're all of same dimension.)

Traditionally I code:

```
library(foreign) # for reading *.dta files

df_1 <- read.dta("df_1.dta")
df_2 <- read.dta("df_2.dta")
...
df_n <- read.dta("df_n.dta") # note: consider 'n' being an arbitrary defined integer

df_lst <- mget(ls(pattern = "df[0-9]")) # combine dfs into list
```

Now I want to accomplish this in one brief step.

I attempted this loop which won't work - most likely due to defining a variable within quotation marks:

```
# initialize list
df_lst <- list()

# read and combine dfs into list
i <- 0
while(i < n) {
  i = i + 1
  df_[i] = read.dta("df_[i].dta")
  c(df_lst, df[i])
}
```

Moreover I'd rather prefer a function than a loop.

How can I reach my goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [rio](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rio/index.html):

```
rio::import_list(dir(pattern = "df[0-9]"))
```

This will return a list of the data frames.

(Generally speaking, there's no need to import data files into the global environment before putting them into a list.)

*Full disclosure: I am the maintainer of rio.*

Comment: Just great! How can I define the directory? E. g. `rio::import_list(dir(pattern = "data/df[0-9]"))` seems not to be working.

Comment: (Throws "Error in if (!grepl("^http.*://", file)) { : argument is of length zero".)

Comment: Are they in a subdirectory? Then you probably need something like `dir("./data", pattern = "df[0-9", full.names = TRUE)` I suspect. Basically, that argument to `import_list()` should just be a vector of relative or absolute file paths.

Comment: Yes they are. Working perfectly, thx! What is `full.names = TRUE` doing?

Comment: Gives you paths rather than filenames in the specific directory.

Comment: Is there an option to preserve the `names(df_lst)` of the data frames in the list?

Comment: @jaySf Not currently possible, but I've added an issue to add that functionality: https://github.com/leeper/rio/issues/162.

Answer (score 1):

for the loop, use paste to recreate the name:

```
# initialize list
df_lst <- list()

# read and combine dfs into list
i <- 0
while(i < n) {
   i = i + 1
   df_[i] = read.dta(paste("df_[",i,"].dta",sep=''))
   c(df_lst, df[i])
}
```

and define 'n' (I assume you did it, but does not appear defined in the text)

cheers

Fer

Comment: Yes, 'n' is considered defined, I made a comment to my code, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Using `assign()` and `do.call("list",...)`, you can do this with a function:

```
# list of filenames matching pattern 
fnames <- list.files(pattern = "df_[0-9].dta")

# function to read, assign to global env, and return data
dtafx <- function(i){
  df <- foreign::read.dta(fnames[i])
  assign(gsub(".dta", "", fnames[i]), df, envir = .GlobalEnv)
  return(df)
}

# apply function to filenames, combining dfs into list
df_lst <- do.call("list", sapply(seq_along(fnames), dtafx, simplify = F))
```